# Firebase Functions are not working after deploying (MAC - OS)

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Trying to deploy firebase functions..which deploys fine after giving warning on the first try

console warning:

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only functions:
To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions
[image: Firebase Console Error While Deploying]

redeploying does not give any error in console and functions deploys without any problem

but calling the function does not show any logs in firebase console, while giving this error in chrome console
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /sampleFunc from this server.

Comment: If your HTTP type function doesn't work at all after deployment, contact Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Regarding why when calling the firebase function you received the permission message, have you tried calling the firebase functions using incognito mode?
Did you make any changes to your Firebase functions, then you redeployed? Or did you just redeploy the functions without any changes?

Comment: Regarding the error messages when deploying your Firebase functions, have you tried to debug your functions locally using the emulator? https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator

Comment: @KevinQuinzel 
-same result from incognito.
-This was a completely new function..since then I have redeployed it couple of times with some minor changes. 
-for now I am running the functions locally on emulator and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

So I contacted firebase support and there seems to be an issue with functions:
here is what they replied:

There is an ongoing issue with the deployment of new functions as they are deployed as private, please update to the latest version 8.0.0 of the CLI with the command: npm install -g firebase-tools, which it might fix the error.

Our engineering team is already working to solve this issue, however there is no tell on when this fix will be released. At the moment the only workaround for this is to manually set a function to public using Cloud Console or gcloud CLI.

Let me know if you have more questions 
Cheers,

Comment: Interesting, did the firebase team give you an issue [tracker number](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) where they will post an update when this issue is resolved?
Are your firebase functions being deployed as private by default?

I just deployed some firebase functions and I could see from the [GCP Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) that they were deployed as public.

Comment: I did this to find how they were deployed: 

Went to the Cloud Functions dashboard for your project in the Google Cloud console.
Clicked the checkbox next to the function that you want to make public/private.
Click **Show Info Panel** (in the top-right corner) to show the Permissions tab.

Comment: Tracker Number
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2086